# server health monitor

Tags: monitoring, health

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Server health monitoring software](https://serverfault.com/questions/154465/server-health-monitoring-software)

hello
i need to a server monitoring solution.
the solution must be able to alert when a server goes down
also i want, the solution be flexible to work with various servers for example it must be able to monitor servers like, webserver,application server, DB server and ...
i want to know is any open source solution is available for me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Even though [splunk](http://www.splunk.com) is not open source I recommend you check it out, it can do pretty much everything you want and it can be extended. It's free up to a certain data throughput (it's quite costly if you want to get the shareware).

Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183977/what-commercial-and-open-source-competitors-are-there-to-splunk for open source solutions.

Comment: thank for your helps.
i need to java solution.
i want to have an api and customize it myself.
is any free solution is available?

Answer (score 1):

Nagios (http://www.nagios.org) is an open-source monitoring solution which comes with a whole range of default plugins for monitoring things like host status, CPU usage, service states etc.

It's also fairly easy to write your own plugins to monitor your own business specific metrics (see http://nagiosplug.sourceforge.net/developer-guidelines.html).

What is your target platform?

Comment: thank for your helps. i need to java solution. i want to have an api and customize it myself. is any free solution is available?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an open-source system in Java, take a look at [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/).  It's not as widely used as Nagios but has a pretty good reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ProtoMon Lite](http://protomon.badhim.com) it's free and has a lot of options. Unfortunately it's not open source.